# How to select specific row element to plot chart in python

Tags: python, pandas, plot, linechart

```
df.set_index('day', inplace=True)
df.groupby('Country Name')['Cumulative Confirmed'].plot(legend=True)
```

I use this code and it plot chart from every country I have in the CSV, how can I choose only some of the country like China?

Comment: Cannot access callable attribute 'loc' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Comment: Oh whoops, you could filter before grouping though using isin.

Comment: Sorry, Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want filter only one country filter by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), then `groupby` is not necessary:

```
df.loc[df['Country Name'].eq('China'), 'Cumulative Confirmed'].plot(legend=True)
```

If need filter multiple countries from list use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
countries = ['China','Italy', 'Slovakia']
(df[df['Country Name'].isin(countries)]
      .groupby('Country Name')['Cumulative Confirmed'].plot(legend=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a list of Countries, filter your dataframe, and plot

```
country_list = ['CountryA', 'CountryB', 'CountryC']
df.query('`Country Name` in @country_list')\
    .groupby('Country Name')['Cumulative Confirmed'].plot(legend=True)
```